# Search Option - populateViewHolder prob - how to Fix

Tags: java, database, firebase, search

I want search option with Firebase database To my App .. In which i Have Watch Video from youtube.. But under the description They give code .. i download and use  but all the error i have fix but these days populateViewHolder is not working .... but the code have populateViewHolder ... I give Code in Here .. plz fix it for me ...
**give me exact code plz .. And mention u r editing which java class ... full code from that class**

**This is Search Activity**

```
package com.qoutes.martins.myqoutes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mSearchField;
    private ImageButton mSearchBtn;

    private RecyclerView mResultList;

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");


        mSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

        mResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();
                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
            }
        });

    }

    private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(

                Users.class,
                R.layout.list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery

        ) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getStatus(), model.getImage());

            }
        };

        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    // View Holder Class

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName, String userStatus, String userImage){

            TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            TextView user_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


            user_name.setText(userName);
            user_status.setText(userStatus);

            Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


        }

    }
```

}

**This is Users object class**

package com.qoutes.martins.myqoutes;
public class Users {

```
public String name, image, status;

public Users(){

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Users(String name, String image, String status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

```
**Thanks  In Advance **

***If You Say Me To Change Code Then Kindly Give Me Full Set Of Code***
```

Answer (score 0):

i also come across this issue once but i was able to solve it by initializing your linearlayoutmanager using variable, like this----Linearlayoutmanager layoutmanager = new Linearlayoutmanager(this);----and make sure to add ---adapter.startListening---or set the lifeCycler to your firebase options..,...
And i also recommend you to use algolia for search substring for better search results because firebase doesn't have such features yet